# Why do some PDF files only work in certain apps?

Tags: pdf, offline

I recently enrolled in a study coaching which provided me with the study material in the form of a PDF document. But I can only view it in their provided app. They allow us to download PDF files for offline viewing. I found those PDF files in the `android/data/"institute name"` folder, but I can't open them in another app (it displays a corrupt message).

Is there any way to see that file in a different PDF viewer? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFmR4.png)

Comment: Do the files have the .pdf extension? Perhaps adding it will fix this if you can move them to an outside service like Google Drive

Comment: Yes,it does contain .pdf extension

Comment: Can you share one of the files?

Comment: @rhens here's a link of a pdf file https://drive.google.com/open?id=183it-q0NFtcXPkJ8LrAhohygNf7n9Y-N

Answer (score 1):

The file you shared is not a PDF file.

It seems to be encrypted because of digital rights management (DRM)<sup>*</sup> in order to prevent to be opened outside of that provided app. Unless you can decrypt it, you won't be able to open it in a different application.

---

<sup>*</sup> At the start of the file, you can see `application/vnd.intertrust.drm.aes128.cbc` and `urn:marlin:kid:`:

- aes128 refers to [AES encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)
- [Intertrust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertrust_Technologies_Corporation) is a company that provides DRM
- [Marlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlin_(DRM)) is a DRM platform